# How do I build a C-based MPI program on Windows with Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, compiler-errors, mpi

I have downloaded the following tools:

- Eclipse Kepler (4.3.2)
- Eclipse Parallel Development Platform (7.0.5)
- Microsoft MPI

I'm running a 32-bit install of Windows 7, and I'm trying to create a setup that I can use to develop MPI applications.

This happens whenever I try to build the included MPI "Hello World" project:

```
09:19:16 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project MPI Test ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
mpicc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\MPI Test.o" "..\\src\\MPI Test.c" 
Cannot run program "mpicc": Launching failed

Error: Program "mpicc" not found in PATH
PATH=[stuff]


09:19:16 Build Finished (took 119ms)
```

I already know that I don't have mpicc on this computer, but I was hoping that the Microsoft MPI implementation would be able to let me build these programs in addition to running them. Is this the case? If so, can I configure Eclipse to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft MPI is not indicated as a supported environment on the [Eclipse Parallel Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/ptp/) web page.

You could download MPICH2 [here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2staging/goodell/downloads/index.php?s=downloads) (Win32 build available).

Edit:

you can find a step-by-step procedure to set up your PTP install [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PTP/environment_setup_70). More specific, you can find what you need to set up MPI [here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.ptp.pldt.help/html/setup.html). You need to go to the Eclipse Preferences, in Parallel Tools > Parallel Language Development > MPI and describe your MPI environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, doing this leaves me with the same error message. I found a tutorial here: http://vkn13.blogspot.com/2011/09/mpich2-with-eclipse.html but it wasn't helpful.

Comment: After following the tutorial, I changed the build command from mpicc to gcc, and the program now compiles and runs (with only one process, but that's down to arguments)